# want to add one year to date in start date text box wilh minus one day and return it in end date textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, date

I want when I enter date in dd/mm/yyyy in start text box (TxtStartDate), it will automatically fill the end text box (TxtEndDate) by adding one year minus one day in above entered date for example if the user input is '15/04/2014' then the output will comes '14/04/2015'
please provide your solution with javascript, jquery or asp.net c#

my HTML Code:

```
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td style="text-align: right"><asp:TextBox ID="TxtEndDate" runat="server"    
  Width="177px" AutoPostBack="True" style="height: 22px"></asp:TextBox>   
  </td>
     <td style="text-align: right">end date</td>
   <td style="text-align: right">
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextStartDate" runat="server" Width="177px"  
      AutoPostBack="True"  style="height: 22px"></asp:TextBox></td>
       <td style="text-align: right; direction: rtl;">
        start date
        </td>
         </tr>
```

I have two textboxes in my asp.net c# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, you can take advantage of `OnTextChanged` event of asp.net textbox controls. To automatically generate the code, you can directly double-click on the `txt_Start` in the design mode. For this event to be triggered, you will need to add this `AutoPostBack="True"` to `txt_Start` Please see the following:

```
  Start:<asp:TextBox ID="txt_Start" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txt_Start_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Label ID="lbl_wrongdate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
  <br />
  End: <asp:TextBox ID="txt_End" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then, the logic is very straightforward, I think it is self-explanatory:

```
    protected void txt_Start_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime start = new DateTime();
        //using System.Globalization;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txt_Start.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out start))
        {
            DateTime end = start.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
            txt_End.Text = end.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            lbl_wrongdate.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_wrongdate.Text = "Wrong date format. Allowed formats is dd/mm/yyyy";
            txt_End.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

After you enter a valid date to `txt_Start` and press `Tab`, you will see `txt_End` is automatically set.

Comment: it's return an error (String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.)

Comment: can you try `04/11/2015` ? it should be in this format `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: ya but i need it to be in this format dd/mm/yyyy and what if user enter it in different format

Comment: @feby see the code again, I updated. Do not forget to add this to the top of the page `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: @feby did it work? If it did, it would be great if you mark my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

in C#,its simple,can use `date.AddYears()` and `date.Adddays()`

first add 1 year by using

```
Date dtedate = new Date()
dtedate=txtstartdate.Addyears(1)
```

then substract 1 day by

```
dtedate1=dtedate.Adddays(-1)
```

then assign to the control

```
txtEnddate=dtedate1
```

hope this helps

**updates:**

You can simplify the code to a single line.so it the code will be

```
Date dtedate = new Date()
dtedate=datetime.parse(txtstartdate.text,"dd/MM/yyyy");
txtEnddate.text=convert.tostring(dtedate.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1));
```

Comment: There is no `Date` type in .Net.Correct type name is `DateTime`. And methods\properties cases also invalid and your code wont compile, so you need to specify correct methods\properties casing in your answer to not confuse others.